# Better way to submit a form with custom variable (prompt)?

Tags: php, javascript

I'd like to submit a form with a custom variable from the `prompt()` function.

Submitting a form uses the code

```
document.formname.submit();
```

But that will just submit the form, what I want is:

```
var iInvoiceID = prompt("Please enter the invoice ID");
document.formname.submit(); // But it should send iInvoiceID within $_POST aswell
```

One way could be: after the prompt, set an input type = 'hidden' to `iInvoiceID`'s value, and then submit the form. But is there a better/cleaner way todo this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the way you suggested,

> after the prompt, set an input type = 'hidden' to `iInvoiceID`'s value, and then submit the form. But is there a better/cleaner way todo this?

Is the best and cleanest of doing what you need.

**Edit:**
As for your edit, I think `document.formname.submitbutton1.click();` should do the job.

Comment: Alright, and my form has multiple submit buttons, is there any way to 'fake' a specific submit button?

Comment: Nevermind, my edit was wrong. I have it fixed already. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your edit, it seems like you could do something like this:

```
$('#myform').submit(function() {
    $('#my_hidden_input').val(prompt('Please enter the invoice ID'));
});
```

Comment: Nevermind, my edit was wrong. I have it fixed already. Thanks anyway.